how to make apt echo dpkg commands it runs (or better - would run, in -s mode)?
i want to better understand how apt does what it does, to figure out which options i need to set in configuration
is there a way to echo / log dpkg commands it would run (preferably in -s mode, without actually running them)?
i searched in:
man apt-get
man apt.conf
/usr/share/doc/apt/examples/apt.conf
/usr/share/doc/apt/examples/configure-index
found nothing that seems like it
